# Best IDE(Netbeans or eclipse) for android application development?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans IDE for develop  mobile application J2ME. Now i'm switchover to android app development. I configured android in netbeans and developed small application.But most of my friends suggest me to use eclipse IDE.I don't know whether continue netbeans or move to eclipse.Which is the best IDE for developing of standard android application?

Comment: Going with the official tooling from Google's Android developer site is probably the best bet.

Comment: FWIW, they seem to be switching from current Eclipse-based Android Developer Tools (http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html) to IntelliJ-based Android Studio (currently in beta): http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse is an IDE VERY similar to Netbeans and also quite easy to install with [this bundle.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

The reason why `Eclipse` is better is because it has official support from `Google`. `Netbeans` plugins are made by community, not the official android staff.